# Why are radians treated like a quantity while degrees are treated like a unit?

Tags: complex-numbers, angle

According to this answer about using [Euler's Identity in Degrees](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1368049/706407), radians and degrees are interchangeable.

Why is it that:$$(e^i)^{\pi/2}=i=(e^i)^{90^\circ}$$
But: $$i^{2/\pi}\neq i^{1/90}$$

Edit: Im well aware $2/\pi \neq 1/90$

Comment: When you write $(e^i)^{90^\circ}$, it's unclear what the term ``$90^\circ$" means. Is that a number? If so, what number is it? If not, then how can it be an exponent? I would not write that expression at all.  If you interpret $(e^i)^{90^\circ}$ to mean $(e^i)^{\pi/2}$, then of course the equality written is true. On the other hand, there is no question how to interpret $i^{1/90}$, and so $i^{2/\pi}$ is clearly not equal to $i^{1/90}$.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for the reply. So are you saying that $\pi$ the number and $\pi$ radians are different?

Comment: @littleO For example: is $e$ to the $\pi$ radians the same as $e$ to the $180$ degrees

Comment: Radians are a dimensionless quantity. It is defined as a length over a length. You cannot raise to the power of a quantity with a dimension. If you think of $90^\circ$ as just being $90$, then your equality certainly does not hold. If you think of $90^\circ = \frac{\pi}{180} 90$ then your equality does hold true. Frankly, you should forget degrees ever existed.

Comment: What do you mean by "$e$ to the $\pi$ radians"? An exponent must be a *number*. So what *number* is the exponent?

Comment: @littleO: is $i90^{\circ}$ a number?

Comment: @tomasliam: the last bit about forgetting degrees existed is helpful. If I recall correctly Taylor series only work for radians anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comments given by myself and littleO, let me provide an answer that I hope you will find thorough enough.

When you make the statement
$$ (e^i)^{90^\circ}=i $$
you require to clarify what you mean by $90^\circ$. Really, there are three flavours of answer.

1. $^\circ$ is a unit, in which case you cannot take its exponent and the statement does not make sense.
2. $^\circ$ is a dimensionless quantity in its own right, in which case $90^\circ := 90$ and we have $ (e^i)^{90^\circ} \ne i $.
3. $^\circ$ is a dimensionless quantity defined as $a^\circ := \frac{\pi}{180}a$, in which case $ (e^i)^{90^\circ} = i $.

To add further clarification, I will briefly comment on why $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=i$. Raising a real number by an imaginary number has the effect of rotating it around the complex plane and scaling it to magnitude $1$. 3Blue1Brown has an excellent video of why this is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ. The number $e$ is special as it is the unique number such that the arclength of rotation is exactly equal to the exponent (i.e. $e^{ai}$ rotates the number $1$ through an arclength of $a$). The reason for this is to do with the property that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x=e^x$. The arclength from $1$ to $i$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=i$. This is why radians is useful as it is a measure of arclength. Degrees were used historically as 360 is highly divisible, however calculus doesn't care about this property.

I understand that argument is a little rough, but you should watch the video for a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: I actually have watched that video! So if I understand what you're saying: degrees are only useful when converting to radians.

Comment: Yeah basically. I am saying that for most purposes degrees are not useful as they are not based on any nice geometric properties. Radians is the natural way to measure angle.